# How to load an address by street attribute

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, customer, address, array

I can load an address using the following code:

```
$addresses = $addressObj->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('firstname', $addressData['firstname'])
        ->addAttributeToFilter('lastname', $addressData['lastname'])
        ->addAttributeToFilter('city', $addressData['city'])
        ->addAttributeToFilter('postcode', $addressData['postcode'])
        ->addAttributeToFilter('telephone', $addressData['telephone'])
        ->load();
```

The issue is that `street` is an array when returned in the address object so how can I add `street` into my filters above?

I know I could load all the addresses and loop through them in code then compare the array with my data but I would like to avoid this step if possible a it's extra overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('street', 'somewhere');
```

or this, if you want `like` filter

```
->addAttributeToFilter('street', array('like'=>'%somewhere%'));
```

Even if the street is returned as an array, in the database is kept as a single field. The values in the array are concatenated by `\n`.
If you are looking for an exact address that is on 2 lines this should do it:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('street', 'somewhere\nelse');
```

Comment: Ahhh, right. I didn't think to look at the actual database field (long day I guess). Many thanks Marius.